# Add a custom field to checkout form in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a custom field to checkout form of Woocommerce. The field is showing how I want it but, the name and id attribute are wrong. Here's my function to create my field.

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_infos'] = array(
        'type'      => 'textarea',
        'label'     => __('Notes de la commande', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Commentaires concernant votre commande', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

Here's how I call it in the form:

```
<?php woocommerce_form_field( $checkout->checkout_fields['billing'], $checkout->checkout_fields['billing']['billing_infos'], $checkout->get_value( 'billing_infos' ) ); ?>
```

When I inspect my field this is what I get:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide woocommerce-validated" id="Array_field"><label for="Array" class="">Notes de la commande</label><textarea name="Array" class="input-text " id="Array" placeholder="Commentaires concernant votre commande" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
                </p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. The first argument of the function I was calling was wrong.

Here's how I should call it:

```
<?php woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_infos', $checkout->checkout_fields['billing']['billing_infos'], $checkout->get_value( 'billing_infos' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: where should i put this line? on function.php

Answer (score -2):

if you are still looking for solution There is simple plugin for it.

here is link.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-checkout-field/

Thanks.

Comment: Although that link might help the OP, you shouldn't post URLs as answers. If the link changes or the site goes offline, your answer becomes useless. Instead, you should post this as a comment once you have enough reputation. Thanks.

Comment: also, it wordpress plugin link. Its never changes.